# Svg image not displaying

Tags: html, image, svg, cross-browser, base64

If I display my web page in IE it works but it's not displaying in other browsers. For example in Google Chrome. However if I look at the code everything looks correct - and if I copy base64 string from there into omnibox, the image is displayed.

```
<svg x="84" y="300" style="cursor: pointer">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" style="fill:rgb(142, 185, 200);stroke:black;stroke-width:1;">
    </rect>
    <image x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" href="data:image/png;base64,[CrazyBase64String]">
    </image>
</svg>
```

Edit: - actual code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<svg x="0" y="300" style="cursor: pointer">
    <image x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" href="data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,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">
    </image>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this embedded in an html page? If so how (inline or via object or via img)? What is the mime-type of the page? what is CrazyBase64String?

Comment: @RobertLongson yes, it is in html page. I am not sure what do you mean, but svg is in the body tag of html. I haven't got any mime-type because the code is on the page. And CrazyBase64String is base64 string representing my image (for example R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////
wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4ML
wWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw== )

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a valid base64 string. please add the actual string to the question.

Comment: Paste your _actual_ code in your question

Comment: well, I have edited it in question. If I save this as file.html it works only in IE browser. All other browsers nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SVG the attribute to link an image is not href, it's xlink:href. If you change the attribute it will display.

```
<image x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" xlink:href="...
```

IE Should require this so you could report it as a bug to Microsoft.